# Javascript to clear form field on button click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, user-input, textinput

I have a field called 'inputaddress' which a user types address details into, so they can perform a google map geocode.

What I would like to do is when the user clicks on the 'searchfortheaddress' button, it will perform the geocode but will then clear the 'inputaddress' field.

Could someone perhaps tell me please how I can clear the field.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("inputaddress").value = '';
```

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Would `$('#inputaddress').html("");` or `document.getElementById('inputaddress').value=""` work?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("inputaddress").value = '';
```

Comment: fixed it a second before you posted that comment.  jquery comes far more naturally than plain javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming that u id your input address field `addr`
just add this code to the `onclick` event of your `searchforaddress` button

```
document.getElementById('addr').value="";
```

like this (i am assuming is of ur `searchforaddress` button is `searchforaddress`)

```
    document.getElementById('searchforaddress').onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById('addr').value="";
};
```

Comment: All, many thanks for taking the time to reply and for your help and solutions. Kind regards Chris